# I get CORS error on javascript module file

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

When I add a spline 3d element in javascript I have to use module to use it and then I get that error it says
**ccess to script at 'file:///D:/js%20learn/spline.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.**

Please help me. I need to use that spline 3d element

I tried to upload that javascript file on a server to use it as an http link but I don't know how

Comment: Annoying as it is for web development, you will need to run a local server to serve files and prevent these 'origin' issues. These are there to prevent sites from accessing files and folders on your computer. The easiest way I know is to install NodeJS, then in terminal install a global http server with `npm install http-server -g`. After that, open your folder in terminal and run `http-server` and you should be ready to start development while avoiding any protocol, origin and file issues.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a web server to serve over the `http` protocol. For development you can use a `localhost`. The easiest way I know how to do that is to install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your system. Then open a terminal or command line prompt (I think on windows this is `run`) and install the server stuff by running this command:

```
npm install http-server -g
```

Now drag the root folder of your project into the terminal to go to that folder (or somehow get to that folder, if you are on Windows I can't exactly tell you). From that location, run this command:

```
http-server
```

It will log a bunch a things, but most importantly it will allow you to visit your project as if it was a website on a server. It's usually located in the `localhost` domain, like `localhost:8080`. This should prevent any CORS/origin/protocol issues in general (there are some other cors issues you *could* run into but deal with those when you get to them).

There are also solutions that don't require you to use a terminal at all like [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/). Point it at your folder and start a server. But if you are going to continue in web development, making yourself familiar with terminal and command line will be a boon.